# URL, как называется каждый блок

Tags: url

Вопрос с одной стороны глупый, но как называется каждый "блок" в URL адресе? Т.е. если есть некий адрес https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, то как называется  элементы questions и ask. 
Это "сегменты", "блоки"...  как это называется?
Я сейчас пишу подобие документации и надо нормальным языком обозвать

Comment: Неужели google об этом ничего не знает?

Comment: Просто путь. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

Comment: А если я хочу сказать, что между  questions и ask находится еще оно слово, например test, и оно означает.... то как это сказать. Между "частями пути"  questions и ask находится "часть пути" test?

Comment: Называйте эти части пути папками, если угодно

Comment: @andreymal Лучше, наверное, (под)каталогами или (под)директориями. Папка (folder) как-то больше воспринимается как визуальное отображение ссылки на каталог (directory).

Comment: @Akina имхо, вкусовщина, я эти термины как синонимы использую)

Comment: @andreymal так-то да... мне, например, ни в жисть не придёт в голову назвать папку "Мои документы" - каталогом, а каталог, в котором оно располагается, типа "C:\Users\Akina\Documents" - папкой. Так то мне... Но вот в документации я бы как раз ратовал за чёткое разделение.

Comment: @Akina, учитывая, что папка (в терминах Windows) может быть как каталогом ФС, так и виртуальным объектом (например, Мой компьютер), ИМХО, логичнее именно термин папка, т.к. части URL могут не соответствовать реальным каталогам, а являются чаще виртуальными

Comment: @ГерманБорисов В точки зрения локального для веб-сервера описания - полностью согласен. А вот для внешнего наблюдения... хотя, может, единообразие тут и правда лучше. В общем, я накинул, теперь пусть у автора вопроса голова болит.